# ASP.NET Core Forwarded Headers only working with minimal API

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, iis

Troubleshooting an issue with Forwarded Headers and I've created a test app. The scenario is an ASP.NET Core MVC application hosted on IIS placed behind a load-balancer. The problem is generated links in the app are created with http:// while the load-balancer uses https:// and sets the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header to `https`.

In my test app, if I set it up like this with the minimal API, the Forwarded Headers work and `HttpContext.Request.Scheme` is `https`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders =
        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}

app.UseForwardedHeaders();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

However, if I use the old `Program` and `Startup` method, which the production app uses, the Forwarded Headers no longer work, and `HttpContext.Request.Scheme` comes through as `http`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;

namespace TestApp;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        host.Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder =>
            {
                builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });

        return builder;
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders =
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseForwardedHeaders();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(e => e.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
        );
    }
}
```

I assumed that they would work the exact same way. But repeated tests back and forth show that they do not. I have made sure to set the `ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED` environment variable to `true` using `web.config`. Why is the minimal API version the only one working?

Comment: According to this official document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-7.0, I checked your program code. Actually strange, it should work. When running the program code for reverse proxy, have you checked the event viewer?

Comment: @TengFeiXie I somewhat figured it out, it's related to hosting Out-of-process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working. I neglected to mention that this app uses `OutOfProcess` hosting model, which contributed to why it wasn't working. Changing the `ConfigureServices` method to set  `ForwardedHeadersOptions.ForwardLimit` to `2` and clearing the `KnownNetworks` and `KnownProxies` lists fixed it.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ForwardedHeaders =
            ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        options.ForwardLimit = 2;
        options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
        options.KnownProxies.Clear();
    });
}
```

`OutOfProcess` hosts the app behind an IIS reverse proxy which uses up the default value of `1` for `ForwardLimit`, though I do not know why it was working with the Top Level Statements version in the question. `WebApplication.CreateBuilder` and `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` must be configuring `ForwardedHeadersOptions` differently.

**Note: The above configuration got Forwarded Headers working in this situation, but should be used with caution in production.**