# How to get client IP address for isolated .net 8 running in Azure Functions (breaking change?)

Tags: azure-functions, .net-8.0, azure-http-trigger

We have been successfully using http header `X-Forwarded-For` in a .net 7 isolated worker process for Azure Functions to retrieve the originator's Client IP address.

[We just upgraded to .net 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide) and this header has disappeared. There appears to be nothing similar when I dump out all the passed headers.

I think this could be a regression/bug with running .net 8 in an isolated worker process for Azure Functions but perhaps someone knows of a reason/config change that needs to be made to make this work again?

I should say, in case it's relevant, that we're using Azure Functions as the API for Static Web App (via [Bring Your Own Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/functions-bring-your-own))

Good examples of how to extract this header can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582553/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-azure-functions-c) - I would stress - this is not that our code is broken, it's that the header that used to exist no longer does (under some circumstances that I cannot pin down directly)

A bit more info on this... dumping out the headers I can see that when it works I get a comma-separated list of IP addresses for `x-forwarded-for` with my client IP address as the first one.

Also I see that the `Host` is the DNS entry to the Azure Functions.

**Working headers**
[image: Working headers]

But, when it doesn't work, I get just the single Azure Data Centre IP (which is then used by ASP.NET Core integration middleware to set the `RemoteIpAddress`) and the `Host` is `localhost:port`

**Not working headers**
[image: Not working headers]

Also note the capitalisation changes in the Header names - whilst I realise that doesn't matter as they are case insensitive, it does suggest that there are two different code-paths or configurations that are being used.

Comment: Please share your working `.NET 7` function code

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya Googling "How to get client IP address in Azure functions" will show you some standard examples of extracting a header variable and specifically how it used to work - there are several examples here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582553/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-azure-functions-c - the thing is this did used to work and now the header value is no longer in the headers collection.

Comment: are you trying locally or after deploying to azure. Is your function behind load balancer or proxy?

Comment: Hi @VivekVaibhavShandilya - this is after deployment (i.e. it's a live problem) - we dump out all the headers in the logs and this one has disappeared. We are using Azure Static web app with BYOF proxied API to Azure Functions

Comment: this worked for me in direct access to function. [code](https://i.imgur.com/KSP5WOk.png), [log](https://i.imgur.com/5YTMJMX.png), [output1](https://i.imgur.com/Tgt7ehf.png), [output2](https://i.imgur.com/XMRuUw2.png)

Comment: Thanks for trying. So this is with .net 8 and isolated worker? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows

Comment: yes, It is on`.NET 8 Isolated` worker.

Comment: Hi @VivekVaibhavShandilya I tried this - it does not work - it returns the IP address of the Microsoft Data center (i.e. it is not "Forwarding" the Client IP address)

Comment: Hi @Kram, is there an equivalent of `ForwardedHeadersOptions` in Isolated Functions? This example describes a similar problem but unfortunately not Azure Functions specific. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75768674/2325216

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
  var remoteIP = req.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
}
```

Comment: I guess you didn't try this? No it doesn't work. Previously needed to use the `X-Forwarded-For` header now it's gone... googling "How to get client IP address in Azure functions" will show you examples of how it used to work.